# Group By only certain values a field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of newsfeeds.  There is a field name that tells me what section it came from, called "newsfeedSection".  I currently grab the 30 most current records to display.  Certain newsfeeds are combined such as "You have posted 5 new photos this week.".  That statement would combine 5 different newsfeed records about photos.  The problem is if someone posts 30 photos, the page would only display one post (as it would combine the photos into one post).  Even if the page combines posts, I still what to display 30 newsfeeds.

The field newsfeedSection have values such as:

```
100 - Profile updates
200 - Photo upload
300 - Image upload
400 - Status updates
```

Now only 200 and 300 are combined.  Is there anyway to do this using one SQL statement?
I've tried GROUP BY and DISTINCT but was not successful.

Any help would be great.  Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

Some of the SQL statements I've tried are:

```
SELECT newsfeedID, newsfeedSection FROM newsfeed GROUP BY newsfeedSection ORDER BY newsfeedID DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

and

```
SELECT newsfeedID, DISTINCT newsfeedSection FROM newsfeed ORDER BY newsfeedID DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

The issue im having is that its also grouping the sections which are not suppose to be grouped, such as 100 and 400.

**EDIT 2:**

Sample Data:

```
newsfeedID    newsfeedSection
1             100
2             100
3             200
4             200
5             300
6             300
7             400
8             400
9             400
```

Only the 200's and 300's should be grouped.  Lets say i want the 6 most current posts.  I want:

```
9             400
8             400
7             400
6             300
4             200
2             100
```

However, when I try to GROUP BY or DISINCT, it groups them all such as

```
9             400
6             300
4             200
2             100
```

Is this possible to get the first results with one query?

Comment: You should show what you have tried, along with sample data and desired results (all by editing your question).

Comment: I have changed my question and added what I have tried.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: This still needs a little clarification in the data set. Please post a sample set of rows in the table along with a sample set of what you would like the query to produce.  Are the numeric values `100,200,300` `newsfeedID`, or part of the `newsfeedSection` column?  `GROUP BY` is meant to be used with aggregate functions (`COUNT(),MAX(),SUM(),`etc) but MySQL will allow you to use it without, producing non-reliable results.

Comment: I have updated it a second time to show sample data and the results I want vs results im getting.  Thanks for the help everyone!